# How to learn ”the way of ABAP"?

Tags: abap

I never worked with SAP solutions. I have a reasonable understanding of business, but no accounting background. How to learn ABAP on examples that will simultaneously enlighten me with the "way of SAP"?

It doesn't have to be a deep knowledge, just something to start for somebody who was in the world of Python and C# but needs understand how SAP world works.

(this is not a duplicate of ["Learning SAP-ABAP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388540/online-reference-learning-sap-abap))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Learning ABAP is not particularly difficult if you know other programming languages.

Let's first distinguish between ABAP and ABAP OO. ABAP is the old, procedural language and ABAP OO is its extension with classes.

ABAP has the usual control structures, like if-then-else or loops. Its syntax takes a bit of getting used to (I found especially annoying the part about putting or not putting spaces before parentheses), but is definitely doable.
There are some structures you don't find in C++ and C#, for example the grouping of functions in function groups, which have their own local variables, so if you call something that is in a different function group, things can get messy.
But generally, if you understand scope and namespaces, it shouldn't be a problem.

I found ABAP OO pretty straightforward compared to ABAP, because it basically only added the classes / packages that I knew from C++ / C# before.

How to learn them, I would propose the following for someone who is new to ABAP and wants a DEEP knowledge of it (see later the more functional aspects):
-buy yourself a proper ABAP book, e.g. something from SAP Press
-don't read it just yet
-start with a web course or a simple book, along the lines of "learn ABAP in 24 hours"
-start coding
-as you are coding, you will inevitably ask yourself: "how does this and that work? is the PERFORM using pass-by-reference or pass-by-value for passing the arguments?" Look those questions up in your proper ABAP book
-probably after a few months, you will be familiar enough with the language that you can read through the book without falling asleep

Just a caveat: It IS a useful skill to know ABAP programming, but even if you don't consider the other technologies SAP consists of (like workflow or PDF Forms, that don't have anything to do with ABAP), there are still a lot of frameworks that differ in their logic. So just like even though you know C++, knowing the Win32 framework does not mean you can start banging out code that runs under UNIX, knowing ABAP does not mean that you can work productively in a specific module right away. Unfortunately, SAP modules tend to use different frameworks, some of them more reused than others.

If you do not want a deep knowledge of ABAP, but want to understand the SAP modules functionally, you should consider using the products themselves in addition to programming and learning about the functional aspects.

I'm afraid there is really no quick way to learn how the "SAP World" functions; you need to have a bit of technical, functional and also architectural knowledge for that and since the modules are so vastly different from all those aspects, it takes a lot of time until you can have a vast overview of everything. But even with technical and some functional knowledge you would be well on your way; as they say, "in SAP, nobody expects you to know everything".

Comment: This is a very good answer.  If your company has the scratch, sending you to one of SAPs training classes will be helpful.  ABAP has some quirks.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two different sets of issues you should be looking for:

1. Knowledge of ABAP as a programming language
2. Knowledge of the "Business Domain" that your writing your software for and its implementation in SAP - tables, forms, programs, reports etc, (and each of the modules such as FI HR etc. is more than a normal person can usually be proficient in)

(1) gives you general knowledge on how to write a program, read and update the database, and maybe write a GUI. But the programs that you write will almost always be in the context of (2), so you will need to know that as well.

If you want to get started, it is best to have some general knowledge of the ABAP language, the business domain can't really be learned from a book. Actual project work is much more helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Start by downloading one of the [netweaver trial systems](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/nw-downloads) from sdn.sap.com (choose one of the ABAP trial systems).

For reference you have the ABAP manuals online [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/e1/8e51341a06084de10000009b38f83b/frameset.htm) (the reference documents also have a lot of small example programs). For more example code you can enter transaction SE38 (report editor) and search for programs starting with BC or starting with DEMO (put BC* in the name box and press F4).

Comment: transaction SE83 (Reuse Library) can also help. Under se38 there is a menu item "Environment / Exemples" with a lot of code example, with full explanations about performance...

Answer (score 3):

since you asked me to respond to this question as well. I was hired as a sap-java-developer because there are very very few on the market, even though I didn't know anything about sap java before I entered. I got advice from my co-workers and learned as fast as possible to become productive. It wasnt such a big deal in the end.
I'm one year into the business now but I'm still in a newbie-state. The sap technology environment is huge. SDN (Sap Developer Network) is my best friend whenever I'm stuck.

It definitely helps when you end up in a company with sap-knowledge because you dont have to build up all systems from scratch and you have the licenses for the various sap products at hand. Most trial versions from sap just wont do the trick on the long run.